# Bound View wont display even after INotifyPropertyChanged - WPF MVVM C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I cannot find my error, though I am quite new. I appreciate a set of eyes on this to find where I went wrong. My MainWindow hosts three UserControls - a menu, a panel, and a work area. The Content of the Panel is driven by the Menu. The rest will be for another day.

Here is the content of my MainWindow.cs

```
public class MainWindowVM: BaseViewModel
{
    #region private variables
    private IPageViewModel _currentPanelVM;
    private List<IPageViewModel> _vmList;
    #endregion

    #region public properties
    public List<IPageViewModel> VMList
    {
        get
        {
            if (_vmList == null)
                _vmList = new List<IPageViewModel>();
            return _vmList;
        }
    }
    public IPageViewModel CurrentPanelVM
    {
        get{ return _currentPanelVM; }
        set
        {
            _currentPanelVM = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPanelVM");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region ctor
    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        VMList.Add(new P_Items_VM());
        VMList.Add(new P_Vendors_VM());

        CurrentPanelVM = VMList[0];

        Mediator.Subscribe("masterdata_items", LoadItemPanel);
        Mediator.Subscribe("masterdata_vendors", LoadVendorPanel);
    }
    #endregion

    #region private methods
    private void ChangeViewModel(IPageViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!VMList.Contains(viewModel))
            VMList.Add(viewModel);

        CurrentPanelVM = VMList.FirstOrDefault(vm => vm == viewModel);
    }
    private void LoadItemPanel(object obj)
    {
        ChangeViewModel(VMList[0]);
    }
    private void LoadVendorPanel(object obj)
    {
        ChangeViewModel(VMList[1]);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="CWApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CWApp"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:CWApp.Views"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CWApp.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVM />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:P_Items_VM}">
            <v:P_Items_UC/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:P_Vendors_VM}">
            <v:P_Vendors_UC/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <DockPanel>
        <DockPanel Name="Menu" 
                   DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                   LastChildFill="true">
            <v:_MenuUC/>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel Name="Panel" 
                   DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="2,2,0,2">
            <Expander Name="expContents"
                      ExpandDirection="Left" IsExpanded="True" 
                      Margin="0.4,0,0,0.2">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Content" FontWeight="Bold">
                        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Expander.Header>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPanelVM}" />
            </Expander>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel Name="WorkArea" 
                   DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0,2,2,2">
            <v:_WorkAreaUC/>
        </DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

When the MainWindow loads it correctly displays the simple Panel I have created as seen below.
[MainWindowDisplaySample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TXuA.png)

MenuUC.cs

```
public class _MenuVM: BaseViewModel
{
    #region private variables
    #endregion

    #region public properties
    public ICommand ShowItemsPanel
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(
                  param => Mediator.Notify("masterdata_items", ""));
        }
    }

    public ICommand ShowVendorsPanel
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(
                  param => Mediator.Notify("masterdata_vendors", ""));
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

}}

When I step through the code, I can watch as the Commands are created, Mediators are notified and subscribed, and values in the MainWindow are changed. This is the part that drives me nuts.

This line is successfully loading the correct ViewModel: CurrentPanelVM = VMList.FirstOrDefault(vm => vm == viewModel);

and the OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPanelVM") is being called too, but the ViewModel doesn't get updated. I've been at this for hours and I cant figure out what I'm missing. Help a brother out?

Comment: `ContentControl.Content` must contain View components, not ViewModel. ViewModel can be set for example to ContentControl's `DataContext`. What's inside `P_Items_VM` class?

Comment: Do you accidentally re-install DataContext in Code Behind Window?  
  
Show how you have implemented the partial class MainWindow.

Comment: And you need to set DataTemplate for IPageViewModel interface.
Otherwise, ContentContent will only display the type name in property Content.

Comment: @EldHasp you nailed it. As I was typing out "no, there is no code behind" I went to look at the mainwindow anyway and sure enough I did add "//this.DataContext = new MainWindowVM();".  Ugh. 

I removed that and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @EldHasp can you help me to understand why this did not work? I totally understand and fixed it but now I'm trying to grasp the concept of what was happening - order of operations or whatever - so I can be watchful and aware of this kind of thing in the future.

Comment: Show the complete Code Behind MainWindow.
What was when it did not work correctly.

Comment: @EldHasp     public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainWindowVM();
        }
    }

I needed only to comment out the datacontext as you suggested. My question is why setting the datacontext in both the xaml and codebehind caused this behavior. I understand that was wrong and fixed it, jsut trying to understand the problem now.

Comment: I assumed you have more code in the Code Behind Window.
If that's all the code, then it should work too.
This creates two instances of the ViewModel - this is overkill. But it shouldn't make the code unworkable.